# Were there any other religions before Islam that their followers should convert to Islam?

Tags: hadith, history, conversion

You could imagine that with the advent of a new religion, any followers of the last religion would be required to convert to the new religion.

1. Which followers of which religion converted to Islam, when Islam
   came on the scene?
2. How did they know that they had to convert to Islam?
3. Are there documents in the history?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Are you asking what religions were around during the coming of Islam? In Mecca? The whole world?

Comment: i ask there same question ... and they answer on their mind.. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23160/2188

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi, u asked a nice questions(s). But I assume you'll get more answers in case limiting your question; Since it consists of few questions which perhaps get times to reply all of them... otherwise it would be interesting to know regarding your questions. Good luck friend.

Answer (score 1):

Al-Ahnaf (Follower of Ibraheem a.s.) were the majority in Arabia, although Christians and Jews were also present.
All religions previous to Islam are required to convert to Islam as it is the final divine religion that unites all previous religions and believe in all the Prophets before Prophet Mohammed (PBUH).
There are mentions of Prophet Mohammed (PBUH) in Bible and Torah, who was mentioned as "Ahmed", but modifications for them occurred over time and mostly those mentions were distorted or removed, but they may be still found in less-modified holy books.

Comment: There are no mentions of Achmed in the Bible or Torah, nor is there any evidence of such..

Comment: @Affable the gospel of Barnabas in some of the European translations mentions Muhammad several times. Also, there is controversy that "Paraclete" in the Gospel of John refers to Muhammad.

Comment: Not sure but maybe you can use [4:159] to back your answer better: "**And there is not one of the followers of the Book but most certainly believes in this before his death, and on the day of resurrection he (Isa) shall be a witness against them.**" which include both the Christians and Jews, but its Ta'weel has not come, yet. Also, as @MahmoudAl-Qudsi has stated according to Hadeeth the holy prophet's name in Bible is فارقلیط whose translation to Arabic is Ahmed. The language of Jesus peace be upon him was 'Ibri while 3/4 of Injil was written originally in Greek! Godspeed.

Comment: Also see the following links that contain good info about this, some are in Persian though: [here](http://islampedia.ir/fa/1389/12/%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%AC%DB%8C%D9%84/), [here](http://www.hawzah.net/fa/magazine/magart/5824/7004/84835) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraclete#Paraclete_in_Islam).

Comment: @owari just a minor correction, but Jesus Christ spoke Aramaic, not Hebrew.

Comment: This has been asked at C.SE [here in re:Barnabas](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8469/what-official-statements-represent-christianitys-position-on-the-gospel-of-barn) and [here in re: Ahmed](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/7853/name-of-ahmed-in-the-scripture/7857#7857).  In sum, as a Christian imam, I can unequivocally tell you that Barnabas was never considered Biblical.  It was Gnostic - never Christian.  I don't say that Ba'hai speak for Muslims, Don't tell me that Gnostics speak for Christians. :)

Comment: Also, within Christianity, the definition of the Paraclete is very clear - It is a a Greek word *parakleos* meaning one who comforts.  For Christians, this has always been the Holy Spirit.  I am aware of classic Islamic writers who have this interpretation, but no Christian would ever make it.